# When I try to access process.env.PWD in my Meteor app, it says that it's undefined

Tags: node.js, meteor

I just started to experiment with Node.js and Meteor for a project of mine.
For this project, I need to upload files. Therefore, I've installed this package : [meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads).
During the Quick Start part, I'm asked to put this code in my server/init.js file :

```
//file:/server/init.js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/',
    checkCreateDirectories: true //create the directories for you
  })
});
```

Problem : my **process.env.PWD** is *undefined* and that obviously crashes the app whenever I try to upload file(s).
With the node.js prompt, I've tried to access the **process** variable (it worked), the **process.env** variable (it worked again) and finally the **process.env.PWD** variable (undefined).

I've hardcoded the path to the different directory required by the package as a work-out and that worked, the file was uploaded (but it's not very smoothed as I will need to change that for others environnement).

But I can't manage to understand why I don't have a **process.env.PWD**.
If anyone has any idea or question, be my guest (and thanks in advance).

EDIT : Oh, and I tried to find an answer on the Internets without any success, hence my lack of understanding.

Comment: We finally decided to use `/opt/projectname` folders. They won't be overwritten on deploy, you can map any drive to the folder etc. Using `process.env.PWD` is not a reliable way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `process.cwd()` if you want the current working directory instead of relying on possibly missing environment variables.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that doesn't seem to work. The `process.cwd()` returns a Windows formatted path, that's causing a breaking error when Meteor restarts.
`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\C:\Dev\file_upload\.meteor\local\build\programs\server'`
(The double 'C:\' is not a typo ^^)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 var homeDir = process.env.HOMEPATH;
 tmpDir: homeDir + '/uploads/tmp'`
```

Comment: process.env.HOMEPATH could be undefined on some platforms just like process.env.PWD that could point to different locations or be undefined too.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late... but I've been chasing this for awhile and it's a bug in the uploads package and PWD no longer works in Meteor. On Windows, you can pre create the directories (I am using **meteor_bootstrap**.serverDir to get the base and then backing up from there to the app root). But you CANNOT call checkCreateDirectories because of https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads/issues/66 ( see my comment under user genyded which has the details).

So, until that issue is addressed, if you want something in the app root...

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var path = Npm.require('path');
var meteor_root = fs.realpathSync(__meteor_bootstrap__.serverDir + '/../' );
var application_root = fs.realpathSync( meteor_root + '/../' );

// if running on dev mode
if( path.basename( fs.realpathSync(meteor_root + '/../../../' ) ) == '.meteor'){
    application_root =  fs.realpathSync( meteor_root + '/../../../../' );
}

Meteor.startup(function () {
  UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: application_root + '/../../../../../.uploads/tmp',
    uploadDir: application_root + '/../../../../../.uploads',
  })
});
```

...but you MUST pre create the dirs first.